# Like "show desktop", but with a row of icons across the bottom

Tags: finder, desktop

One effect of using a Magic Mouse while being slightly clumsy, is that I sometimes perform gestures I did not know existed and certainly had no intention of performing.

Recently, I managed to get my iMac, running Big Sur, into a something that looked like the "show desktop" mode, except that there was a row of file icons across the bottom of the screen, larger than the "normal" desktop icons. (I keep the Dock to the right). It looked like some kind of full-screen folder preview.

What did I do? (And where is `M-x view-lossage` when you need it?)

Comment: Could it be "App Exposé" ? For me it shows enlarged recent files/dirs in xcode for example. NOTE sometimes it works with CTRL+↓ or F10

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or capture?

Comment: No screenshot i'm afraid, as I have no idea how I got into this situation (nor how iI got out of it, for that matter). The "app exposé" hypothesis seems reasonable, though; i'll try it when I'm back at the same computer again.

Comment: I believe that this is App Exposé. Row at the bottom displays minimized windows i.e. those windows where yellow circle in upper left is clicked (or ⌘ + M).